# Defect Management Tool for Outsourced Testing Operation

Tags: web-apps, software-development, database

I have a need for some software recommendations for defect management. However this is a little away from the norm. There exists an outsourced testing operation. It takes in systems for testing, performs manual and automated functional and regression testing on the systems and then needs to publish the results to various different clients.

I have looked at defect tracking systems (on the internet) and most seem to be focussed on supporting Agile development methods and moving the testing closer to the development operation. All of these things I applaud, but neither are relevant to this company. JIRA seems to be the de facto front runner, but also looks like it might be overkill for my needs as I only need a subset of defect logging, tracking and reporting requirements as detailed:

- Testing will *always* be separate from development and follow *after* development has completed (I am aware of the implications of this, please don't waste time telling me why this is bad- the company tests other companys' products and they are not engaged by the original system supplier company)
- No workflow is required to move items around between testers and developers
- External clients will need to be able to access the defect system to observe, query and report on the defects that have been found
- Some defects will be visible to *all* external clients and some will only be visible to subgroupings of external clients
- The defect record will need to "carry" several external references (one for each external client) mapping the defect to that each client's relevant test case

The system will preferably be 100% cloud-based, but if locally hosted will need to run on the MS stack.

External access should be via a standard web interface which presents via a website linkable from the company's own portal/website.

In fact the requirement is for little more than a bug-tracking database with a nice website front end, and would probably be fairly easy to write from scratch but then, someone *must* surely have done this already somewhere?

Apologies if tags incorrect, this is my first visit to this site and there don't seem to be any tags specifically for defect management.